# Twilio Upload SSL certificate error: "Header is missing for certificate or private key."

Tags: twilio

I am trying to upload a SSL certificate in order to configure "Link Shortening". I have purchased an SSL cert from ZeroSSL.  I am using the following command:

The command I used:

```
curl -X POST https://messaging.twilio.com/v1/LinkShortening/Domains/$DOMAIN_SID/Certificate \
--data-urlencode "TlsCert=$tlsCert" \
-u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
```

I am getting the following error:

```
{"code": 30116, "message": "Header is missing for certificate or private key.", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/30116", "params": {}, "status": 400, "user_error": true}%
```

I am hoping someone could shed some light on what I might be doing wrong.

I am using the document https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/how-to-configure-link-shortening#step-5-uploading-tls-certificate as the guide for uploading the TLS certificate.  I have a ca_bundle.crt, certificate.crt and private.key from ZeroSSL.  The gap I may have is that I am not generating the proper PKCS#8 private key.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the link provided in the error message  (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30116)? It reminds you to use the PEM format and points you to a Wikipedia page that tells you what that is.
It sounds to me like it's looking for something like the following at the start of the file and complaining that it can't find it:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: I am following the directions outlined here:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/how-to-configure-link-shortening#step-5-uploading-tls-certificate

The format appears matches what the docs say.  My fear is that I am unable to generate PKCS#8 format correctly.  I am getting a ca_bundle.crt, certificate.crt and private.key from ZeroSSL.  What are the steps to properly generate the TLS Cert that Twilio is asking for?

Comment: @TylerIves, notice that the "example of the correct formatting for the TLS certificate and private key" shows that what is to be url-encoded for the upload is the contents of the certificate.crt and private.key files concatenated together. Are you ensuring the shell variable tlsCert contains exactly that, and that all other variables mentioned in the instructions are populated correctly?

Comment: You can also get curl to read the data from a file by using `@filename` instead of the variable (replace filename with the actual filename). See the `--data-urlencode` description in the `curl` man page for more information. For this you would create a new file using `cat certificate.crt private.key > tlscert.pem` and use `@tlscert.pem` instead of `$tlsCert`.

Comment: I ended up just using TinyURL service. It was much simpler to implement and I was up and running less than an hour.  I had also submitted a ticket with Twilio and their solution wasn't very clear either. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: OK, good to hear you found a solution! Be sure to give feedback to Twilio about their service / complexity etc., so they might have some more incentive to lift their game.